# How can I use System-Versioned Temporal Table with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2016, temporal

I can use temporal tables in SQL Server 2016. Entity Framework 6 unfortunately does not know this feature yet. Is there the possibility of a workaround to use the new querying options (see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt591018.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) with Entity Framework 6?

I created a simple demo project with an employee temporal table:

[image]

I used the edmx to map the table to entity ([thanks to Matt Ruwe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742142/entity-framework-not-working-with-temporal-table)):

[image]

Everything works fine with pure sql statements:

```cs
using (var context = new TemporalEntities())
{
    var employee = context.Employees.Single(e => e.EmployeeID == 2);
    var query = 
      $@"SELECT * FROM [TemporalTest].[dbo].[{nameof(Employee)}]
         FOR SYSTEM_TIME BETWEEN
         '0001-01-01 00:00:00.00' AND '{employee.ValidTo:O}'
         WHERE EmployeeID = 2";
    var historyOfEmployee = context.Employees.SqlQuery(query).ToList();
}
```

Is it possible to add the history functionality to every entity without pure SQL? My solution as entity extension with reflection to manipulate the SQL query from `IQuerable` isn't perfect. 
Is there an existing extension or library to do this?

**edit:** (Based on the commentary by [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168070/pawel))

I tried to use a Table-valued Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetEmployeeHistory(
    @EmployeeID int, 
    @startTime datetime2, 
    @endTime datetime2)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT 
        EmployeeID,
        [Name], 
        Position, 
        Department, 
        [Address],
        ValidFrom,
        ValidTo
    FROM dbo.Employee
    FOR SYSTEM_TIME BETWEEN @startTime AND @endTime
    WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
);
```

```cs
using (var context = new TemporalEntities())
{
    var employee = context.Employees.Single(e => e.EmployeeID == 2);
    var historyOfEmployee =
      context.GetEmployeeHistory(2, DateTime.MinValue, employee.ValidTo).ToList();
}
```

Do I have to create a function for each entity or is there a generic option?

Comment: Have you considered using a TVF?

Comment: It is possible to get the correct entity type? In this example that GetEmployeeHistory retruns Employee instead of "unknown" type?

Comment: Yes. It is possible to get the right entity type. I don't remember from the top of my head but the designer may want to add a type to the model for your TVF. You don't want that - you want to use an existing type. The important thing is that TVFs returns the right columns so that it is possible to materialize entities.

Comment: Little update, if you use EFCore: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFCoreTemporalSupport/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initial support for Temporal Tables has been added here: [e7c0b9d](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/e7c0b9de29904a8bc0b59aba3458c75d05d6f9fb) (model/metadata part) and here [4b25a88](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/4b25a8871355ae44846b173a02915b01ec469bc9) (query part) and will be available in the next preview (Preview 8), as well as in current nightly bits.

*Usage:*

Mapping entity to a temporal table can be done in the OnModelCreating, like this:

```c
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTemporalEntity>().ToTable(tb => tb.IsTemporal());
```

additional configuration is also supported - history table name/schema, names for period start and period end columns

```c
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTemporalEntity>().ToTable(tb => tb.IsTemporal(ttb =>
{
    ttb.HasPeriodStart("SystemTimeStart");
    ttb.HasPeriodEnd("SystemTimeEnd");
    ttb.WithHistoryTable("MyHistoryTable", "mySchema");
}));
```

Migrations are supported so existing entities can be converted to temporal.

*Querying:*

```c
var myDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
context.MyTemporalEntities.TemporalAsOf(myDate).Where(e => e.Id < 10);
```

Supported operations: `TemporalAsOf`, `TemporalAll`, `TemporalBetween`, `TemporalFromTo`, `TemporalContainedIn`.

*Some limitations and considerations*

- Queries that use temporal operations are always marked as ``NoTracking`. Multiple entities with the same key could be returned from such queries and EF would not be able to resolve their identities properly otherwise.
- Temporal operations are supported directly on `DbSet`, rather than `IQueryable`. In case of inheritance, they can't be applied on `OfType` operation. Instead, use:

```c
context.Set<MyDerivedEntity>().TemporalAsOf(...);
```

- Navigation expansion is only supported for `AsOf` operation, since it's the only temporal operation that guarantees consistency of the result graph. For other temporal operations navigations must be created manually using `Join`.
- When expanding navigation, the target entity must also be mapped to temporal table. Temporal operation gets propagated from source to the target. Navigating from temporal to non-temporal entity is not supported.

```c
context.Customers.TemporalAsOf(new DateTime(2020, 1, 1)).Select(c => c.Orders)
```

will return customers and their orders as of Jan 1st 2020. Temporal operation gets applied to customers AND orders automatically.

- Set operations (e.g. Concat, Except) on arguments mapped to temporal tables are not supported. (issue tracked here [#25365](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25365))

Quote from [maumar](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4693#issuecomment-889471707)

Answer (score 4):

No, I am afraid, you cannot. I have been back & forth with `Microsoft gurus` on this front.

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4693).
And the best advice I have found is to use `FromSql` as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt795184.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 4):

**Yes you can** with a little effort ...

Intercepting EFF intents when trying insert or update generated always columns and avoid errors like

> ```
> "Cannot insert an explicit value into a GENERATED ALWAYS column in table 'xxx.dbo.xxxx'. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the GENERATED ALWAYS column, or insert a DEFAULT into GENERATED ALWAYS column."
> ```

After that it's work like a charm (already in production on Azure Db)

**Example of implementation** EFF6 based on columns (StartTime y EndTime) based on:

[entity-framework-not-working-with-temporal-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742142/entity-framework-not-working-with-temporal-table)

[insert-record-in-temporal-table-using-c-sharp-entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253965/insert-record-in-temporal-table-using-c-sharp-entity-framework)

[dbset-attachentity-vs-dbcontext-entryentity-state-entitystate-modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987806/dbset-attachentity-vs-dbcontext-entryentity-state-entitystate-modified)

Thank you!

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Ubiquité.Clases
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Evita que EFF se haga cargo de ciertos campos que no debe tocar Ej: StartTime y EndTime
    ///     de las tablas versionadas o bien los row_version por ejemplo
    ///     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742142/entity-framework-not-working-with-temporal-table
    ///     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253965/insert-record-in-temporal-table-using-c-sharp-entity-framework
    ///     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987806/dbset-attachentity-vs-dbcontext-entryentity-state-entitystate-modified
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// "Cannot insert an explicit value into a GENERATED ALWAYS column in table 'xxx.dbo.xxxx'.
    /// Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the GENERATED ALWAYS column, or insert a DEFAULT
    /// into GENERATED ALWAYS column."
    /// </remarks>
    internal class TemporalTableCommandTreeInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
    {
        private static readonly List<string> _namesToIgnore = new List<string> { "StartTime", "EndTime" };

        public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
        {
            if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace == DataSpace.SSpace)
            {
                var insertCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbInsertCommandTree;
                if (insertCommand != null)
                {
                    var newSetClauses = GenerateSetClauses(insertCommand.SetClauses);

                    var newCommand = new DbInsertCommandTree(
                        insertCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                        insertCommand.DataSpace,
                        insertCommand.Target,
                        newSetClauses,
                        insertCommand.Returning);

                    interceptionContext.Result = newCommand;
                }

                var updateCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbUpdateCommandTree;
                if (updateCommand != null)
                {
                    var newSetClauses = GenerateSetClauses(updateCommand.SetClauses);

                    var newCommand = new DbUpdateCommandTree(
                        updateCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                        updateCommand.DataSpace,
                        updateCommand.Target,
                        updateCommand.Predicate,
                        newSetClauses,
                        updateCommand.Returning);

                    interceptionContext.Result = newCommand;
                }
            }
        }

        private static ReadOnlyCollection<DbModificationClause> GenerateSetClauses(IList<DbModificationClause> modificationClauses)
        {
            var props = new List<DbModificationClause>(modificationClauses);
            props = props.Where(_ => !_namesToIgnore.Contains((((_ as DbSetClause)?.Property as DbPropertyExpression)?.Property as EdmProperty)?.Name)).ToList();

            var newSetClauses = new ReadOnlyCollection<DbModificationClause>(props);
            return newSetClauses;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// registra TemporalTableCommandTreeInterceptor con EFF
    /// </summary>
    public class MyDBConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public MyDBConfiguration()
        {
            DbInterception.Add(new TemporalTableCommandTreeInterceptor());
        }
    }
}
```