# entity framework (MSSQL 2016) + xUnit test - tries to update "GENERATE ALWAYS" column SysStartTime

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2016, xunit.net

I am having a strange problem:
I have a quite simple Login(string user, string pass) method for user login which needs to save last login date of that user:

```
using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var dbUser = dbContext.IdentityUserLogins.SingleOrDefault(u => 
        u.LoginProvider == login && u.ProviderKey == password);
    if (dbUser != null)
    {
        dbUser.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
        dbContext.Entry(dbUser).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        var id = Convert.ToInt32(dbUser.UserId);

        /*other stuff*/
    }
}
```

When I run this from a regular debug, everything works fine. The user I enter is found, his LastLoginDate is updated successfully and its Autogenerated SysStartTime is updated automatically at SaveChanges()

But when I run this method from an xUnit test, it behaves strange.
The test is simple, like this:

```
[Fact]
[Trait("Category", "MyCategory")]
public void LoginTest()
{
    string user = /*user name*/
    string pass = /*get password hash*/
    UserModel user = handler.Login(user, pass);
    Assert.NotNull(user);
}
```

It simply calls that method.

The problem occurs on SaveChanges() call, an exception is thrown:

```
Cannot update GENERATED ALWAYS columns in table 'AppIdentityUserLogin'
```

Our tables use these columns like SysStartTime, SysEndTime and RowVersion, but there are no problems with Entity Framework knowing, how to handle them, this is the only exception - this xUnit test.

The problem is most likely in the dbContext.Entry(dbUser)... line, because when I comment it out, the test passes normally. I even think it is not needed there, because without it everything updates the same in regular debug.
EDIT: Both - xUnit tests and regular debug are using the same ConnectionString.

What could cause this strange behavior? I tried to find some pre-run config, some differences between accessing this method as a test debugger and as a regular debugger, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Where is your dbContext getting the connection string from? make sure they are pointing to the same database?

Comment: Yes they are using the same connection string. I checked that. I updated my question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Since you are updating a connected entity, you don't need to mark the whole object as modified. When you set a new field value it'll automatically mark the specific field as modified. So dbContext.Entry isn't necessary in this scenario

Comment: If you explicity want to mark one field as modified please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
Credit goes to Matt Ruwe and his solution to the [Temporal table problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742142/entity-framework-not-working-with-temporal-table) he had.

I simply had to tell EF, not to try to overwrite the Generated columns. 
In my case I had to set the _namesToIgnore to "SysStartTime" and "SysEndTime" and then put this line in my BaseTest constructor

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterception.Add(new EF.TemporalTableCommandTreeInterceptor());
```

Now everything inserts and updates normally even from xUnit test debug.