# How to exclude some column from .edmx file, *.csdl ,*.msdl, and *.ssdl dynamically using Database first Approach

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first, database-first

what i am trying to do is exclude few column from EF store and EF modal.
for reference 
there are two method :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40742144/4998968

but i want to exclude column when edmx file is created i.e when i connect my database using Ado.net Data modal option i want few columns to be excluded from edmx as if they don't exists in database.
currently i am exploring the entity framework source code but cannot find the exact code that generates .edmx file and store.

example: suppose i have a column "SysStartDate" now i want to exclude this column from all the table having it.

i want to exclude columns from edmx so *.csdl ,*.msdl, and *.ssdl file doesn't include it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: Ignore Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737520/entity-framework-ignore-columns)

Comment: not a duplicate question i am asking for a function or module that is responsible for generating .edmx file.