# Which function/module generates .edmx file in database first apporach?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6

can anyone tell me which function is responsible for generating the .edmx file while using database first approach ?
i am trying to modify the .edmx file when it is generated and exclude some columns from it.

Comment: thats part of visual studio.

Comment: And can't you set a property on the COlumns to exclude?

Comment: i want to exclude properties as if they don't exists in database.

Comment: please check is question for clearification :
https://stackoverflow.com/q/53063836/4998968

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone looking for the same.

edmGen.exe is responsible for generating the .edmx in database first approach.

**file location:** "C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\edmgen.exe"

Answer (score 0):

The ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer (Entity Designer) uses the Update Model Wizard to update an .edmx file from changes made to the database. 
Please see the following link for more information about changes made to an .edmx file: [Changes Made to an .edmx File by the Update Model Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716700.aspx).